# Django Template Error at Circle CI while Writing Test

Tags: django-templates, circleci, django-testing, django-tests

All of my settings work perfectly fine and have no issue as such. Its just that CircleCI is not getting the most simplest possible test work fine. I've created a home page and wrote a test for it. The test at local ubuntu machine runs fine with `python manage.py runserver` and with `pytest` as well. Also installation and configuration works just fine in logs at CircleCI.
I would appreciate if someone can point me to right direction.

My Django Test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class TestPage(TestCase):
    def test_home_page_works(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("home"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "base.html")
        self.assertContains(response, "APTA")
```

My CircleCI config.yml:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      # use `-browsers` prefix for selenium tests, e.g. `3.6.1-browsers`
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.2

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4
      - image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=root
        - POSTGRES_DB=lims

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Wait for db
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m

      - run:
          name: Install
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . envs/test
            pip install .[test]
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python --version
            pip install -r requirements.txt

      - run:
          name: Collect static files
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python apta/./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
      - run:
          name: Test
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python apta/./manage.py migrate --noinput
            pytest
      - run:
          name: Lint
          command: |
            . envs/test
            flake8
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports
          destination: test-reports
```

My pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=apta.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
```

Error I've got at CircleCI:

```
apta/tests/test_views.py F                                               [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________ TestPage.test_home_page_works _________________________

self = <tests.test_views.TestPage testMethod=test_home_page_works>

    def test_home_page_works(self):
>       response = self.client.get(reverse("home"))

apta/tests/test_views.py:8: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py:535: in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py:347: in get
    **extra,
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py:422: in generic
    return self.request(**r)
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py:503: in request
    raise exc_value
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py:34: in inner
    response = get_response(request)
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:145: in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:143: in _get_response
    response = response.render()
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py:106: in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py:81: in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py:63: in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

template_name_list = ['base.html'], using = None

    def select_template(template_name_list, using=None):
        """
        Load and return a template for one of the given names.

        Try names in order and return the first template found.

        Raise TemplateDoesNotExist if no such template exists.
        """
        if isinstance(template_name_list, str):
            raise TypeError(
                'select_template() takes an iterable of template names but got a '
                'string: %r. Use get_template() if you want to load a single '
                'template by name.' % template_name_list
            )

        chain = []
        engines = _engine_list(using)
        for template_name in template_name_list:
            for engine in engines:
                try:
                    return engine.get_template(template_name)
                except TemplateDoesNotExist as e:
                    chain.append(e)

        if template_name_list:
>           raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
E           django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html

venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py:47: TemplateDoesNotExist
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
log.py                     228 ERROR    Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/home/circleci/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: base.html
=========================== 1 failed in 0.85 seconds ===========================
Exited with code 1
```